# The type LoveCalculatorApplicationInitializer must implement the inherited abstract method WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(ServletContext)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

Getting this error even after inheriting onStartup() method:
The type LoveCalculatorApplicationInitializer must implement the inherited abstract method WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(ServletContext).

**Here's the pom.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.seleniumexpress</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-love-calculator</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>spring-love-calculator Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.9</version>
</dependency>
    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring-love-calculator</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
`
```

**Here's the LoveCalculatorApplicationInitializer.java:** problem not resolved even after inheriting

```
`package com.seleniumexpress.lc.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;

public class LoveCalculatorApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
`
```

Comment: `<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>` Java 7? From 2011. Why are you using Java from 12 years ago?

Comment: See abovelinked duplicate. The question might not be the same but the answer is very applicable on your situation too: use Tomcat 10+ or else downgrade Spring to 5-. In other words, simply make sure all the versions are the most recent ones or at least match each other wrt compatibility.